# Unable to create a constant value of type <object>. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: entity-framework

I am using the following code:

```
    public static Grid.GridResult GetExamDetailsForGrid(Grid.GridFilter Filter, int userid, int _user_roleid, int selectedYear,string Tin,string  Measure, DateTime? Startdate, DateTime? Enddate)
    {
        Grid.GridResult _examsEntered = new Grid.GridResult();
        using (var entity = new PQRSEntityContainer())
        {
            ((IObjectContextAdapter)entity).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 120;
            var Measureid = 0;
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Measure))
            {
                Measureid = entity.tbl_Lookup_Measure.Where(m => m.CMSYear == selectedYear && m.Measure_num == Measure)
                             .Select(v => v.Measure_ID).FirstOrDefault();
            }

            var _username = CurrentUser.UserName;
            var npi = FileProcessBL.getNPINumber(userid);
            var cmsYear = selectedYear != 0 ? selectedYear : 0;
            var Newtin= string.IsNullOrEmpty(Tin) ? null : Tin;
            var NewStartdate = Startdate ==null ? null : Startdate;
            var NewEnddate = Enddate == null ? null : Enddate;
            var NewMes= string.IsNullOrEmpty(Measure) ? null : Measure;
            var liDetails = (from ex in entity.tbl_Exam.Where(i => i.Physician_NPI == npi && i.CMS_Submission_Year == cmsYear 
                                                && i.Exam_TIN == (Newtin==null?i.Exam_TIN:Newtin)
                                                && i.Exam_Date >= (NewStartdate == null ? i.Exam_Date : NewStartdate)
                                                && i.Exam_Date <= (NewEnddate == null ? i.Exam_Date : NewEnddate))

                             from exmes in entity.tbl_Exam_Measure_Data.Where(i => i.Exam_Id == ex.Exam_Id 
                             && i.Measure_ID== (Measureid == 0 ? i.Measure_ID : Measureid) ).DefaultIfEmpty()
                             from nume in entity.tbl_lookup_Numerator_Code.Where(nume => exmes.tbl_Lookup_Measure.Measure_ID == nume.tbl_Lookup_Measure.Measure_ID && exmes.Numerator_response_value == nume.Numerator_response_Value).DefaultIfEmpty()
                             join sc in entity.tbl_Lookup_Data_Source on ex.DataSource_Id equals sc.DataSource_Id
                             where exmes.Exam_Id != null  

                             select new MesCasesGrid
                             {

                                 NPI = ex.Physician_NPI,

                                 TIN = ex.Exam_TIN == null ? "" : ex.Exam_TIN,
                                 ExamID = ex.Exam_Id,
                                 //MeasureID = exMes.Measure_ID,
                                 MeasureID = (exmes != null) ? exmes.Measure_ID : 0,
                                 MeasureNum = (exmes != null) ? exmes.tbl_Lookup_Measure.Measure_num : null,
                                 CPTCode = (exmes != null) ? exmes.Denominator_proc_code : null,

                                 ///NumeratorCode = (exmes!=null)?exmes.tbl_Lookup_Measure.tbl_lookup_Numerator_Code.Select(i=>i.Numerator_Code).FirstOrDefault():null,
                                 NumeratorCode = nume.Numerator_Code,
                                 Created_Date = ex.Created_Date,
                                 ExamDate = ex.Exam_Date,


                                 UniqueExamID = ex.Exam_Unique_ID,
                                 PatientGender = (ex.Patient_Gender == "M" ? "Male" : ex.Patient_Gender == "F" ? "Female" : ex.Patient_Gender == "O" ? "Other" : ex.Patient_Gender == "U" ? "Unknown" : ""),

                                 PatientID = ex.Patient_ID,

                                 isEncrypt = ex.IsEncrypt,

                                 PatientAge = ex.Patient_Age,

                                 StatusDesc = (exmes != null) ? exmes.tbl_Lookup_Measure_Status.Status_Desc : null,
                                 ///Type =ex.DataSource,
                                 Type = sc.DataSource,
                                 cmsYear = ex.CMS_Submission_Year

                             }).Distinct().ToList();


            if (_user_roleid == Constants.FacilityAdminID || _user_roleid == Constants.FacilityUserID || _user_roleid == Constants.RegistryAdminID
                || _user_roleid == Constants.SuperCorporateAdminID || _user_roleid == Constants.CorporateAdminID || _user_roleid == Constants.ServiceUserID) // jira-579
            {
                var facilityTins = entity.sp_getFacilityTIN(_username).Select(x => x.TIN).ToList();
                liDetails = liDetails.Where(i => facilityTins.Contains(i.TIN)).Select(x => x).Distinct().ToList();
            }

            var value = Convert.ToBoolean(1);

            foreach (var item in liDetails)
            {
                if (item.isEncrypt == value && item.PatientID != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var patidDecrypt = AesHelper.Decrypt256(item.PatientID);
                        item.PatientID = patidDecrypt;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }

            }

            return _examsEntered;

        }

    }
```

I have recently added the following code above method:
i.Measure_ID == && i.Measure_ID== (Measureid == 0 ? i.Measure_ID : Measureid)

[image: highlighted code recencly added]

When adding the highlighted code to this method I am getting following error:

:Error in  RecordEnteredGridBind()
System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type 'DAL.Entities.tbl_Exam_Measure_Data'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.ConstantTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, ConstantExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.NewArrayInitTranslator.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<TypedTranslate>b__0(Expression e)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.ExpressionBuilder.Internal.EnumerableValidator`3.Validate(IEnumerable`1 argument, String argumentName, Int32 expectedElementCount, Boolean allowEmpty, Func`3 map, Func`2 collect, Func`3 deriveName)
   at System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.ExpressionBuilder.Internal.EnumerableValidator`3.Validate()
   at System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.ExpressionBuilder.Internal.ArgumentValidation.CreateExpressionList(IEnumerable`1 arguments, String argumentName, Boolean allowEmpty, Action`2 validationCallback)
   at System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.ExpressionBuilder.Internal.ArgumentValidation.ValidateNewCollection(IEnumerable`1 elements, DbExpressionList& validElements)

I have tried lot of ways but not working. So, Can anyone help me?

Comment: What's the value of Measureid when you get this error ?

Comment: it is integer type and the default value is 0. I am getting an error when the value is 0

Comment: So what's your logic in your highlighted code in the Where clause when Measureid is 0 ? You want to check if i.Measure_ID is equal to itself ?

Comment: MeasureId value getting based on the measure filter. if the filter value is empty the MesureId value is the 0 and MeasureId value is 0 then I am calling i.Measure_ID is equal to itself.

Comment: var Measureid = 0;
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Measure))
            {
                Measureid = entity.tbl_Lookup_Measure.Where(m => m.CMSYear == selectedYear && m.Measure_num == Measure)
                             .Select(v => v.Measure_ID).FirstOrDefault();
            }

Comment: Hi @auburg, Measureid value getting based on the above condition